# Why is it assumed that the universe started out with a size equal to the Planck length?

Tags: cosmology, big-bang-theory, cosmological-inflation

What if the Planck length is the distance between particles when the universe was very small .
For a spherical ball of 10^ 78 protons that would give the universe a radius of 10^26 X 10^-35 = 10^-9 metres  Is there a reason why this can't be the case? Does the CMB temperature forbid it?

Comment: Oh, and who says that? Earliest Universe we can tell anything would be perhaps having density comparable to Planck density - that's completely different situation than you say.

Comment: I don't think this assumed.  Indeed the usual assumption is that the universe was always infinite in extent (even if this causes philosophical problems.  If the universe had a start (and there wasn't an infinite period of inflation, for example, which come with their own philosophical problems) then our current understanding of matter has difficulty with times at a scale less than one planck *time*  We don't really have a model of reality that can deal with such time intervals, so we can't currently talk about what happened in the first planck time.

Comment: Don't try to treat protons as "balls", or the universe as a fixed spacetime in which a ball of protons exploded.

Comment: The [Planck units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units) are not units which are fundamental in some way.  They're just order of magnitude constants that are *roughly* at levels which mark the range where we don't have good theories.  They feel natural for some purposes - a little easier to manipulate some equations using these units.

Comment: There's some relevant info at [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/123208) & https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/185943/123208

Comment: @James K I should have said a ball of quarks. It is curious though that a black hole of a few solar masses would have a quark ball with radius about the radius of a oroton and the largest black holes a radius about the maximum distance of the strong force. Also that radius for the universe as a whole is not far off some intermolecular bond distances .

Comment: @PM2Ring It was interesting to read in that reference that there should be gamma rays scattering off particles at the Planck length now  from cosmic sources . But I think that would only apply if the particles at the Planck length had electromagnetic properties